# How to print long string in python

Tags: python, spyder

I'm running python 3.6. I'm running a sql query to pull the data. I'm using following query

```
sql="SELECT DISTINCT A.Employee_No "
sql=sql+"FROM Employee A "
sql=sql+"INNER JOIN Dept B1 "
sql=sql+"ON (B1.Dept_ID = A.Dept_ID"
sql=sql+"OR B1.Manager_ID = A.Manager_ID "
sql=sql+"OR B1.Joining_Date = A.Joining_Date "
sql=sql+"OR B1.Group = A.Group) "
sql=sql+"And B1.ACCT_YEAR = '"+str(acct_year)+"'"
sql=sql+" AND B1.surname in ('"+surname+"') "
sql=sql+"AND B1.address IN  ('"+address+"')"
sql=sql.replace(u'\xa0', ' ')
```

But I'm getting some error in my code. So I put a print statement to check my sql. I used `print(sql)` & got partial text as output then I tried following code 
My sql was showing as a series so I changed it to string by using this code & print using textwrap 
     `str=sql.to_string()

     import textwrap
     print(textwrap.fill(str, 20))`
But still I'm getting partial output like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Employee_No
FROM Employee...
```

instead of 20 I also tried 40 but still same output. Can you please suggest me how to see the full long string?
Can you

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. What happens if you just do `print(sql)`?

Comment: Note (unrelated to error): Instead of `sql=sql+"...` use `sql += "...`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce either. Could you be using a fancy IDE? BTW, you are hardcoding parameters is a SQL query which is **bad**. Please learn parameterized queries.

Comment: "SOME ERROR". Don't hold us in suspense. What error?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I'm using spyder

Comment: Then I think you problem is related to spyder. I've just add the tag to the question

Comment: Even better, `sql = """... Stuff ... with ... many .... newlines"""`

Comment: I tried this with `spyder`, but I still cannot reproduce. Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: also, can you paste a full working example of your code, including the imports and the code around (e.g. where you do the sql query)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are executing your sql first and then you try to print the sql string that caused the error. But the error already happened so you are not seeing the string but the original error message (the driver module is printing an error in an abbreviated form). Inspect your sql before executing the query.